# 500 (Internal Server Error) in my AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a button to cancel a hiring event and included in that is a confirmation message using sweet alert but then confirming the action wont go pass my ajax post.

I tried checking the url's if it's correct but then again, all of the url's are correct.

Here is my function in the controller:

```
    {
        $hiring_id = $this->input->post('key');
        $hiring_data = $this->hiring_model->get_hiring($hiring_id);

        $return_a = $this->search_model->update_applicant($hiring_data[0]->applicant_id);

        $return_b = $this->search_model->cancel_hiring($hiring_id);

        if ($return_a > 0 && $return_b > 0) {
            echo json_encode(array('ret'=>'1','new_url'=>base_url('partners/hiring')));
        }
    }
```

Here is my code in the HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-btn--custom" id="cancel_hiring" data-url="<?php echo base_url('partners/hiring/cancel_hiring/'); ?>" data-key="<?php echo $h->hiring_id;?>">
```

And here is my javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#cancel_hiring").click(function(e){
            Swal.fire({
              title: 'Are you sure you want to cancel this hiring?',
              text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
              type: 'warning',
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
              cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
              confirmButtonText: 'Cancel Hiring'
            }).then((result) => {
              if (result.value) {
                console.log($(this).data('url'));
                console.log($(this).data('key'));
                $.post($(this).data('url'), {key:$(this).data('key')}, function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.ret) {
                        console.log('cancelled');
                        Swal.fire(
                          'Success!',
                          'Hiring cancelled.',
                          'success'
                        )
                        var delay = 1000; 
                        setTimeout(function(){ window.location = data.new_url; }, delay);
                    } else {
                        Swal.fire(
                          'Failed!',
                          'Error occured.',
                          'warning'
                        )
                    }
                }, 'json');

              }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If the error is not showing in the `network tab`, change error reporting in `php.ini` -> `display_errors=1` and debug where the actual problem is as `500 Internal Server Error` is vague subject.

Comment: What does the server error log show?